# Test symfony restful api with phpunit and doctrine

Tags: rest, symfony, doctrine, phpunit

I'm trying to pull-of some tests for my RESTful api functions.

For this I did the following:

- Installed PHPUnit.
- Created a new database for testing.
- Created a new enviorment (test) and changed the doctrine config for it.
- Created a test.

My problem is this:

When performing a request (somedomain.com/api/somemethod) -> the requested page doesn't know i'm performing a test on it -> so the data it uses is the production/development database and not the 'test' db i have created for the tests.

(the script using test db, the requested page uses normal configurations).

Is there a way to solve it without touching or modifying the API code/behavior?.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you said you're requesting `somedomain.com` I can only suspect you're firing requests over HTTP.

Symfony is made to be easily testable and you can perform functional test without ever making a **real** HTTP request. Instead, it will make a request object and tell it's kernel to handle it as if it were coming from a real client.

There is a chapter in symfony book on this: [Functional tests](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/testing.html#functional-tests)

If you use method described there (using Symfony BrowserKit client and paths instead of complete urls), Symfony will have it's kernel booted in test environment and will handle request like that.

If, however, for any reason you are unable/don't want to do it that way, and want to fire **real HTTP requests**, I suggest you to make a file in `web` directory called **app_test.php**. In that file you should boot the kernel in **test** environment and make sure your tests are actually hitting that file (instead of `app.php` or `app_dev.php`). However, have in mind that this file will be publicly available and as so, it will cause a security hole so make sure to guard it somehow (check `app_dev.php` for hints). As an idea, you could require specific key to be provided in request header to allow it to pass on. Or if it will be tested from a single machine, you could also guard it by IP, or whatever works for your case.